# Django import issue when updating models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a problem when using import after updating one of my models I get the error ImportError: cannot import name 'Team'

This was my actual model

```
from django.db import models
from registration.models import MyUser
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
```

and I wanted to add the candidat_answer to the Project model from the Response model so I imported the models to be able to use it which gave me that actual code :

```
from django.db import models
from registration.models import MyUser
from survey.models.response import Response
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ForeignKey(Response)
```

However now I get an import error from my registration import views ..

```
from website.models import Team, Project
ImportError: cannot import name 'Team'
```

**init** :

```
"""
    Permit to import everything from survey.models without knowing the details.
"""
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import

from future import standard_library
standard_library.install_aliases()
import sys

from .answer import Answer
from .category import Category
from .question import Question
from .response import Response
from .survey import Survey


__all__ = ["Category", "Answer", "Category", "Response", "Survey", "Question"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a circular import. You don't need to import the models if you are only using them in foreign keys. Remove the imports and use the string `'<app_name>.<Model name>'` instead, for example:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ForeignKey('survey.Response')
```

Comment: Thx Alasdair for your answer, When I try it I get ImportError: cannot import name 'Response'. My models are within a folders models in response.py when the model in question is Response

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is from the error message. The full traceback might show what the problem is.